# Allow only only one cell per column to be selected in HTML table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns and want to add a class 'selectedTd' to on clicked cell. But the condition is, add to one cell in a column. If I select an other cell in same column, then first selected to be deselect and newly clicked cell to be select.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#blank3table td", function() {
  var tdId = $(this).attr("id");
  var x = $(this).closest('tr');
  var columnNo = $(this).index();
  var col1 = x.find('td:eq(' + columnNo + ')').addClass("selectedTd").text();
  /*var columnNo = $(this).index();
  $(this).eq( columnNo ).addClass("selectedTd");*/
  console.log(col1);
});
```

```css
.selectedTd {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">approbation</td>
    <td id="8">enervating</td>
    <td id="9">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in correct path by finding the index but you went up only till `tr`, however for this problem you need to lookup for another `tr's` as well to find the n<sup>th</sup> already selected column(s).

Idea is to find all the n<sup>th</sup> column in all `tr` and remove class from all of them, and now that we have reference of selected column (`this`), Add class to it.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#blank3table td", function() {
 let index = $(this).index()+1;
 $(this)
 .closest('table')
 .find('tr>td:nth-child('+index+')')
 .removeClass('selectedTd');
 
 var col1 = $(this).addClass('selectedTd').text();
 console.log(col1);
});
```

```css
.selectedTd {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">approbation</td>
    <td id="8">enervating</td>
    <td id="9">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have an extension for that Could you please help me

Comment: @nani0077 extension for what ? if you have some other problem,maybe try posting a question someone of us would definitely help you, maybe comment your question and I will see if I can help.

Comment: 1. get selected cell values into a variable then i will save in DB. 2. When page loads cells to be selected which are matching with stored in variable. I hope you got my issue

Comment: @nani0077 while saving run a query to get all selected columns and extract their id's or values and save in DB, when page reloads select all saved columns and add class to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193921/discussion-between-nani0077-and-shubanker).

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery here, this is quite clean and easy to achieve using vanilla ES6 Javascript (as 99.9% of DOM manipulation stuff):

```js
blank3table.addEventListener('click', ({target: cell}) => {
  if (!cell.matches('td')) return; // when clicked on a border, do nothing
  [...blank3table.querySelectorAll('td')] /// get an array of all tds
    .filter(td => td.cellIndex === cell.cellIndex) // boil them down to those with same index as clicked td
    .forEach(td  => td.classList[td === cell ? 'add' : 'remove']('selectedTd')); // and iterate over the remaining, adding/removing the class as necessary
  console.log(cell.textContent);
})
```

```css
.selectedTd {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">approbation</td>
    <td id="8">enervating</td>
    <td id="9">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this code is selecting one cell in a row. I need the same in column

Comment: Changed it to achieve that, which was admittedly harder to get done.

Comment: @nani0077 I was able to simplify the code alot working with the `cellIndex` property of `HTMLTableCellElement` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, I've fixed your cide

```js
$(document).on("click", "#blank3table td", function(){
    var tdId = $(this).attr("id");
    var x = $(this).closest('tr');
    var columnNo = $(this).index();
    $(this).closest('table').find('td').each(function(){
      if($(this).index() == columnNo){
        $(this).removeClass("selectedTd")
      }
    });
    var col1 = $(this).addClass("selectedTd").text();
    console.log(col1);
});
```

```css
.selectedTd {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">approbation</td>
    <td id="8">enervating</td>
    <td id="9">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's selecting one cell in entire table. Actually I need to select one cell in each col

Comment: @nani0077 I've updated code here is fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/etypz9o6/

Answer (score 0):

1. In the HTML add classes to the three columns.
2. When click a cell, first remove the backdroung to the all cells in the column.
3. And finally add the background to the selected cell.

Fixed code : https://jsfiddle.net/tLfz4sa1/3/

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1" class="column1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2" class="column2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3" class="column3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4" class="column1">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5" class="column2">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6" class="column3">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7" class="column1">approbation</td>
    <td id="8" class="column2">enervating</td>
    <td id="9" class="column3">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
const columnsSelectors = ['.column1', '.column2', '.column3'];
columnsSelectors.forEach(columnSelector => {
    const currentCells = document.querySelectorAll(columnSelector);
    currentCells.forEach(cell => {
        cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // remove class selected for all the column
            currentCells.forEach(c => { c.classList.remove('selectedTd')});
            // add selected class to selected node
            this.classList.add('selectedTd');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` selector to remove class from all cells in the same column as demonstrated below.  Also, I would discourage using `document` as a selector for a delegated click event.  Instead use your parent table which is far more specific.

```js
$("#blank3table").on("click", "td", function() {
  // remove class of all cells with same index using `nth-child` selector
  $(this).closest('table')
    .find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')')
    .removeClass('selectedTd');
  // add your class to the clicked cell
  const col1 = $(this).addClass("selectedTd").text();
  console.log(col1);
});
```

```css
.selectedTd {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" id="blank3table">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">perspicuity</td>
    <td id="2">fugacious</td>
    <td id="3">eludible</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">incertitude</td>
    <td id="5">perdurable</td>
    <td id="6">ineluctable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">approbation</td>
    <td id="8">enervating</td>
    <td id="9">propitious</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the class from all the **td**'s first.

```
$("#blank3table td").removeClass('selectedTd');
```

Then add the class to that specific **td** like you did. It will work. Please note that, remove the class at the beginning of your function.

```
$(document).on("click", "#blank3table td", function() {
   $("#blank3table td").removeClass('selectedTd');
   var tdId = $(this).attr("id");
   var x = $(this).closest('tr');
   var columnNo = $(this).index();
   var col1 = x.find('td:eq(' + columnNo + ')').addClass("selectedTd").text();
   /*var columnNo = $(this).index();
   $(this).eq( columnNo ).addClass("selectedTd");*/
   console.log(col1);
```

});